# libquickmail - compiling error

Tags: c++, visual-c++

im trying to send some Mails through a c++ program.

Somebody recommended the libquickmail library.

But i think i dont really get it.. First i thought its a command-line only lib but isnt there a way to use it in my c++ Programm?

I put the quickmail.h include file in my directory and included it in my cpp file. In addition to that i put the libquickmail-0.dll the libquickmaillight-0.dll and the quickmail.exe in my folder aswell.

But whenever i try to compile the main file i get the fatal error that "smtpsocket.cpp" and quickmail.cpp are missing. But i dont include it anywhere! So why cant i just use the dll. Shouldnt it be compilable without these files?

Thanks for your help.

oh and btw im using windows, not linux... There are a few .a lib files,but sadly no quickmail.lib or something similar

Edit 1:

After doing what Pavel Skipenes recommended i get the following error:

```
"libquickmail-0.dll" : fatal error LNK1108: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x408"

"libquickmaillight-0.dll" : fatal error LNK1108: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x408"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
1. Go to Project -> Project properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Additional Library Directories
This field is where linker will look for your .dll files. Add the path to your .dll files there.
2. Make sure you have selected under configuration "all configurations" otherwise you might get linking error when trying to compile in different mode that what you are currentlly running on. And select all platforms as well. Those two options are at the top of the window under project property pages.
3. Go to configuration properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies
Here you should **append** the names of the .dlls that are currentlly missing. Make sure that you don't delete what's there now.
4. Compile and link your project.

If you get any error, update your post with error message from the output window.

Answer (score 0):

libquickmail was built for Windows with MinGW-w64 and comes with MinGW-w64 `.a` library  files.

If you're using MSVC then you need a `.lib` library file.

Please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360280/how-to-make-a-lib-file-when-have-a-dll-file-and-a-header-file